# What happens if players prematurely celebrate victory in a cricket match?

Tags: cricket

When batting team needs 4 runs for victory, batsman playing and ball going for boundaries but not completed the boundary the batsman took the stump for enjoying victory. Is that boundary is valid ?

Comment: What caused the ball to not reach the boundary?

Answer (score 2):

The ball didn't get the boundary. Of course it isn't valid.

The batsman isn't necessarily out either, but may have issues with Law 37 *Obstructing the field* and Law 41 *Unfair play*, especially 41.19 *Unfair actions*, if their actions caused the fielders to be disadvantaged in attempting to return the ball to the stumps or to obtain a runout.

The game is not over either. In the absence of prior offences of this type, the umpires are likely to call the ball dead, give a warning to the batting team's captain, award the runs obtained by the batsman up to that point, and continue the game normally.

Comment: I think it depends a little bit on why the ball didn't reach the boundary - if it was due to spectators invading the pitch when the ball was clearly going to the boundary, umpires will do the practical thing and declare the match over.